# How to set the password for a profile created from Rest APIs in Oracle Commerce Cloud

Tags: cloud, atg, oracle-commerce

I successfully created a profile with REST APIs in **Oracle Commerce Cloud (OCC)** preview application with the help of documentation. Also updated the details of that profile using REST API calls.

The password for the profile was not generated, that's pretty obvious.

But how do I login with that user on the preview store environment?

Reference docs for creating a new profile can be found [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/commercecs_gs/FAOCC/op-ccadmin-v1-profiles-post.html) and [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E73348_01/Cloud.16-2/UsingCC/html/s2304createashopperprofile01.html)

Also if possible someone please create a tag for **oracle-commerce-cloud**

Thank you.

Comment: The title and the question in the body do not correspond so it is not clear what you are asking?  Please update ...

Comment: There is existing tag oracle-commerce. Also "commerce cloud" is ambiguous, as there are products from both Oracle and Salesforce that have this name (Oracle Commerce Cloud previously ATG, Salesforce Commerce Cloud previously Demandware)

Comment: I have added the tag, oracle-commerce-cloud, since oracle-commerce and oracle-commerce-cloud are different products and it is clear that the oracle-commerce-cloud is related to the Oracle product.

Answer (score 1):

Information on accessing the preview store environment can be found [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E75910_01/Cloud.16-3/UsingCC/html/s2203accesspreviewthroughtheapis01.html).  The basic steps are:

1. Login as Admin User
2. Create preview user (not required if you have done this already)
3. Login as Preview User

Answer (score 1):

You can define a password for users created from API by enabling the Forgotten Password email in Settings > Email Settings.

After enabling it you should receive the OOTB email with a new temporary password (deprecated) or a token to reset your password in preview or store.